# Stop WorkManager by tag and check if it is running problems

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I have read several articles on how WorkManager works in Android, but I still encounter problems.

This is the my implementation:

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0"
```

And this is my code:

```java
    public class NotificationWorker extends Worker {

        private static final String WORKER_TAG =    
             NotificationWorker.class.getSimpleName();

        public static void start(Context context){

            Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

            PeriodicWorkRequest notificationWorker  =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                    NotificationWorker.class,
                    30,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                    15,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES
                ).setConstraints(constraints)
                .addTag(NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG)
                .build();

            WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                    NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG,
                    ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                    notificationWorker
                );
        }

        public static void stop(Context context) {

            // THIS NOT STOP WORKER !
            WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                .cancelAllWorkByTag(NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG);

           // THIS WORKS BUT STOP ALL WORKERS
           // WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWork();

         }

         public static boolean isScheduled(Context context) {

             // NOT WORKS!
             WorkManager instance = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
             ListenableFuture<List<WorkInfo>> statuses = instance
                 .getWorkInfosByTag(NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG);
            try {
                boolean running = false;
                List<WorkInfo> workInfoList;
                workInfoList = statuses.get();
                for (WorkInfo workInfo : workInfoList) {
                    WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
                    running = state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING | 
                        state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED;
                }
                return running;
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } 
        }

        public NotificationWorker(
             @NonNull Context context,
             @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams
        ) {
            super(context, workerParams);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Result doWork() {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

The WorkerManager starts and works correctly.

The first problem is that **I can't stop it using cancelAllWorkByTag**
But only using cancelAllWork. In my scenario I use only one Workmanager
so it would not be a big problem but **I would like to understand the error**.

**The second problem is how to know if the WorkeManager is running?**
The 'isScheduled' function always returns false.
I have read that with the different implementations something has changed but I don't know how to update the code.

Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if that's just a typo but your "running" variable is set wrong on `isScheduled(Context context)` method, here.

```
for (WorkInfo workInfo : workInfoList) {
     WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
     running = (state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING || 
                    state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED);
}
```

You are using **one |** instead of **two** which means you need to use `||` instead of `|` while doing the check. The variable might be assigned wrongly on the code you sent.

To try to answer your first question: You can try to stop the worker by using this code:

`manager.cancelUniqueWork(NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG);`

The reason behind this is that you're sending the worker with the ID, not with the tag, while enqueue it. The "NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG" is not a tag, but an ID while you're using this:

```
WorkManager.getInstance(context)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                notificationWorker
            );
```

Edit: I just realized you're also calling the wrong method to get the worker you added. The tag may not be added but the ID definitely will. So, instead of `manager.getWorkInfosByTag(NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG)`, use `manager.getWorkInfosForUniqueWork(NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG)` to see if you can **actually fetch your scheduled work.**

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I replaced the methods with the suggested ones and it works. One more thing, if possible, to understand better. In my example I used the same variable (**NotificationWorker.WORKER_TAG**) as id of WorkManager and as tag of PeriodicWorkRequest. This may have created some confusion but to use getWorkInfosByTag and cancelAllWorkByTag what should I have done differently?

Answer (score 0):

You're enqueuing a unique work, so you must use the corresponding `cancelUniqueWork` method (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#cancelUniqueWork(java.lang.String)).  You just happen to be calling the `name` parameter a "tag", but it's not a `tag` as far as WorkManager is concerned.